# How does a web service access a callback on a client when it can't directly connect to that client?

Tags: networking, webserver

Sometimes it's necessary to set up a callback on a client computer when accessing a web service. An example would be [git-credential-manager](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager), which accesses an OAuth Identity Provider ('IdP', ie. Google/GitHub/whatever), to authorise a git access to another server.

To make this work, GCM pops up a browser window to access the IdP login page. When the user has logged in, the IdP contacts a callback URL *on the client* to tell GCM whether or not the user is authorised. The callback URL is always on localhost (`http://localhost/whatever`).

Question: how is this done? The IdP obviously can't access `localhost` directly. Does GCM set up a local server which talks to the browser window? Does the browser arrange for the callback to be routed to the local server, and how?

Comment: "Does GCM set up a local server which talks to the browser window?" Use `netstat` or `lsof` etc. to list processes with open ports and you'll see one being run by it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is in your specific case, but you can basically never assume that a remote system can initiate a connection to some server running on the user's machine.

Instead, the client usually just either keeps a connection alive, through http itself or through websockets, or it just polls a results URL until it gets a failure or a forward to the desired token.